# Using map with a custom function (that returns a data frame) and multiple inputs

Tags: r, purrr

I have a very simple function, that returns a data frame. The function takes three parameters, a dataset, and two variables that are present in the dataframe.

I was hoping to use the map/pmap family of functions to feed a vector/list of inputs and produce a single (long) output dataset. I can't seem to get map/pmap tools to work for me. What can I try next?

The function is pretty basic:

```
library(dplyr)

# Function takes dataset and 2 categorical variables 
# Calculates number of records for each combination of values in the two variables
# Calculates % of var 1 responses for each level of var2
ugh<-function(data, var1, var2){
# add checks to make sure vars on dataset

  tab_n<-data%>%
    group_by_at(c(var1, var2))%>%
    summarise(Numerator=n(), .groups="drop")%>%
    group_by_at(c(var2))%>%
    mutate(Denominator=sum(Numerator)
           ,Pct=Numerator/Denominator*100
# storing names of var1 and var2 for future subsetting
           , Var1=var1 
           , Var2=var2)%>% 
    rename(Var1_levels=var1
           , Var2_levels=var2
           )
}


# Sample output 
combo1<-mtcars%>%ugh(var1="cyl", var2="gear")
# can also run this as: 
# combo1<-ugh(data=mtcars, var1="cyl", var2="gear")
combo2<-mtcars%>%ugh(var1="cyl", var2="carb")
sampleOutput<-rbind(combo1, combo2)

# Trying to use map to generate sampleOutput
var1_vector=rep("cyl", 2) 
var2_vector=c("gear", "carb")

plswork<-mtcars%>%
  map2_dfr(var1=var1_vector, var2=var2_vector, ugh)
```

The error message I get is:

> Error in as_mapper(.f, ...) : argument ".f" is missing, with no default

I've tried using `~` to specify the function and I've tried using map2 and binding rows separately, also tried pmap with a list of inputs... but am not having much luck.

(I am interested also in more efficient ways to summarise a subset of columns from a data frame by a different subset of columns.)

Comment: Try `map2_dfr(var1_vector, var2_vector, ~ ugh(data =mtcars, .x, .y))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few solutions to this problem. I recommend the first because I think its the most clear. I also tweaked your function to fix any use of deprecated/superseded functions/behaviour.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

# Function takes dataset and 2 categorical variables 
# Calculates number of records for each combination of values in the two variables
# Calculates % of var 1 responses for each level of var2
ugh<-function(data, var1, var2){
  # add checks to make sure vars on dataset
  
  tab_n<-data%>%
    group_by(across(all_of(c(var1, var2))))%>%
    summarise(Numerator=n(), .groups="drop")%>%
    group_by(across(all_of(var2)))%>%
    mutate(Denominator=sum(Numerator)
           ,Pct=Numerator/Denominator*100
           # storing names of var1 and var2 for future subsetting
           , Var1= .env$var1 
           , Var2= .env$var2)%>% 
    rename(Var1_levels= all_of(var1)
           , Var2_levels= all_of(var2)
    )
}

# Sample output 
combo1<-mtcars%>%ugh(var1="cyl", var2="gear")
# can also run this as: 
# combo1<-ugh(data=mtcars, var1="cyl", var2="gear")
combo2<-mtcars%>%ugh(var1="cyl", var2="carb")

sampleOutput<-rbind(combo1, combo2)

sampleOutput
#> # A tibble: 17 × 7
#> # Groups:   Var2_levels [7]
#>    Var1_levels Var2_levels Numerator Denominator    Pct Var1  Var2 
#>          <dbl>       <dbl>     <int>       <int>  <dbl> <chr> <chr>
#>  1           4           3         1          15   6.67 cyl   gear 
#>  2           4           4         8          12  66.7  cyl   gear 
#>  3           4           5         2           5  40    cyl   gear 
#>  4           6           3         2          15  13.3  cyl   gear 
#>  5           6           4         4          12  33.3  cyl   gear 
#>  6           6           5         1           5  20    cyl   gear 
#>  7           8           3        12          15  80    cyl   gear 
#>  8           8           5         2           5  40    cyl   gear 
#>  9           4           1         5           7  71.4  cyl   carb 
#> 10           4           2         6          10  60    cyl   carb 
#> 11           6           1         2           7  28.6  cyl   carb 
#> 12           6           4         4          10  40    cyl   carb 
#> 13           6           6         1           1 100    cyl   carb 
#> 14           8           2         4          10  40    cyl   carb 
#> 15           8           3         3           3 100    cyl   carb 
#> 16           8           4         6          10  60    cyl   carb 
#> 17           8           8         1           1 100    cyl   carb

# Trying to use map to generate sampleOutput
var1_vector=rep("cyl", 2) 
var2_vector=c("gear", "carb")

# Method 1 (recommended): use of anonymous functions
map2(var1_vector, var2_vector, \(var1, var2) ugh(mtcars, var1, var2)) %>%
  list_rbind()
#> # A tibble: 17 × 7
#> # Groups:   Var2_levels [7]
#>    Var1_levels Var2_levels Numerator Denominator    Pct Var1  Var2 
#>          <dbl>       <dbl>     <int>       <int>  <dbl> <chr> <chr>
#>  1           4           3         1          15   6.67 cyl   gear 
#>  2           4           4         8          12  66.7  cyl   gear 
#>  3           4           5         2           5  40    cyl   gear 
#>  4           6           3         2          15  13.3  cyl   gear 
#>  5           6           4         4          12  33.3  cyl   gear 
#>  6           6           5         1           5  20    cyl   gear 
#>  7           8           3        12          15  80    cyl   gear 
#>  8           8           5         2           5  40    cyl   gear 
#>  9           4           1         5           7  71.4  cyl   carb 
#> 10           4           2         6          10  60    cyl   carb 
#> 11           6           1         2           7  28.6  cyl   carb 
#> 12           6           4         4          10  40    cyl   carb 
#> 13           6           6         1           1 100    cyl   carb 
#> 14           8           2         4          10  40    cyl   carb 
#> 15           8           3         3           3 100    cyl   carb 
#> 16           8           4         6          10  60    cyl   carb 
#> 17           8           8         1           1 100    cyl   carb

# If you aren't using a version of R with anonymous functions:
map2(var1_vector, var2_vector, ~ ugh(mtcars, .x, .y)) %>%
  list_rbind()
#> # A tibble: 17 × 7
#> # Groups:   Var2_levels [7]
#>    Var1_levels Var2_levels Numerator Denominator    Pct Var1  Var2 
#>          <dbl>       <dbl>     <int>       <int>  <dbl> <chr> <chr>
#>  1           4           3         1          15   6.67 cyl   gear 
#>  2           4           4         8          12  66.7  cyl   gear 
#>  3           4           5         2           5  40    cyl   gear 
#>  4           6           3         2          15  13.3  cyl   gear 
#>  5           6           4         4          12  33.3  cyl   gear 
#>  6           6           5         1           5  20    cyl   gear 
#>  7           8           3        12          15  80    cyl   gear 
#>  8           8           5         2           5  40    cyl   gear 
#>  9           4           1         5           7  71.4  cyl   carb 
#> 10           4           2         6          10  60    cyl   carb 
#> 11           6           1         2           7  28.6  cyl   carb 
#> 12           6           4         4          10  40    cyl   carb 
#> 13           6           6         1           1 100    cyl   carb 
#> 14           8           2         4          10  40    cyl   carb 
#> 15           8           3         3           3 100    cyl   carb 
#> 16           8           4         6          10  60    cyl   carb 
#> 17           8           8         1           1 100    cyl   carb

# Alternatively, using pmap():
args <- list(
  var1 = var1_vector,
  var2 = var2_vector
)

pmap(args, ugh, mtcars) %>%
  list_rbind()
#> # A tibble: 17 × 7
#> # Groups:   Var2_levels [7]
#>    Var1_levels Var2_levels Numerator Denominator    Pct Var1  Var2 
#>          <dbl>       <dbl>     <int>       <int>  <dbl> <chr> <chr>
#>  1           4           3         1          15   6.67 cyl   gear 
#>  2           4           4         8          12  66.7  cyl   gear 
#>  3           4           5         2           5  40    cyl   gear 
#>  4           6           3         2          15  13.3  cyl   gear 
#>  5           6           4         4          12  33.3  cyl   gear 
#>  6           6           5         1           5  20    cyl   gear 
#>  7           8           3        12          15  80    cyl   gear 
#>  8           8           5         2           5  40    cyl   gear 
#>  9           4           1         5           7  71.4  cyl   carb 
#> 10           4           2         6          10  60    cyl   carb 
#> 11           6           1         2           7  28.6  cyl   carb 
#> 12           6           4         4          10  40    cyl   carb 
#> 13           6           6         1           1 100    cyl   carb 
#> 14           8           2         4          10  40    cyl   carb 
#> 15           8           3         3           3 100    cyl   carb 
#> 16           8           4         6          10  60    cyl   carb 
#> 17           8           8         1           1 100    cyl   carb
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it looks like list_rbind() has also been deprecated (https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/803)... but code works perfectly with bind_rows() in place of the list_rbind().

Comment: @Ddfox `list_rbind()` is a function in purrr 1.0.0 that is designed to replace `map_dfr()` (https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/list_c.html, and the superseded functions here: https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map_dfr.html). Both `list_rbind()` and `bind_rows()` use `vctrs::vec_rbind()` under the hood, so it doesn't matter very much which you use.

Comment: Apologies, it turns out my version of purrr was ancient!